# Orchard content items not appearing in dashboard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

The context for this is Orchard 1.8.1 running on an Azure Website (not cloud service) with Azure database.

I've defined a ContentType via the admin UI. The 'Class' type is creatable and not draftable, and contains Autoroute, Body, and Title parts, along with Numeric and Taxonomy fields. The Taxonomy is defined with its terms.

Items can be created via the 'New' menu on the Admin page or via 'Create New Class' from the Content Definition list. I've created a Query and Projection to display all items of type 'Class', and that shows all of them properly on its front-end page.

The problem is in the 'Content' section of the admin page. If I create the item via the 'New' menu, it doesn't appear in the Content listing. If I create it via 'Create New Class' in the Content Definition list, it does appear in the Content listing. But all of them show up in the query.

I've exported the items and reviewed the XML ... nothing different. The following is an item that appears in the Content list:

```
<Class Id="/alias=american-history" Status="Published">
  <NumericField.Credits Value="1" />
  <TaxonomyField.Dicipline Terms="/alias=subjects\/social-studies" />
  <BodyPart Text="&lt;p&gt;This American History course will integrate both Social Science skills with historical content of America and the United States from the early 1600s to the present, as well as education in government and economics. There is a strong emphasis on college preparation, civic participation, and integration with research and technology. Students use will a variety of resources and activities to explore major themes, including the changing face of American society and the United States&amp;rsquo; changing role in the world.&lt;/p&gt;" />
  <AutoroutePart Alias="american-history" UseCustomPattern="false" />
  <TitlePart Title="American History" />
</Class>
```

And this is an example of one that does NOT appear:

```
<Class Id="/alias=economics" Status="Published">
  <NumericField.Credits Value="1" />
  <TaxonomyField.Dicipline Terms="/alias=subjects\/social-studies" />
  <BodyPart Text="&lt;p&gt;The introductory economics course has a strong emphasis on personal finance. Students learn the importance of budgeting and how, through a variety of financial instruments, to make money work for them. Students also learn how the stock market operates by participating in a virtual stock game. In this context, students are introduced to the concepts of stock ownership, the commodities market, supply and demand and the different types of business structures. Students learn how to complete various tax forms and the how's and why's of the American tax system. Students will read the book, Freakonomics, and gain insight on how to look at problems from an economic standpoint. Finally students learn about the different types of economic systems, the circular flow of money through the economy, and government intervention in our economy.&lt;/p&gt;" />
  <AutoroutePart Alias="economics" UseCustomPattern="false" />
  <TitlePart Title="Economics" />
</Class>
```

I started digging through the database to see if I could find the problem, but quickly got lost.

Any idea where I might start looking for the issue? I'm thinking that, if this were a bug, it would have manifested well before I found it and would be causing a hue and cry, so I'm thinking it's something in my setup somewhere.

Thanks for any help I can get on this one.

-- Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the common part for it to appear in the contents list because it needs that to order by date and probably some security stuff related to who owns the content, though I'm not sure about that one :)

Update from Bertrand: You also need to mark the content type as Listable in the Content Type definition.

Comment: While it doesn't show up in the export, looking at the content definition shows that CommonPart is indeed there.

Comment: Also, make sure that the "listable" checkbox is checked in the content type definition.

Comment: Making it "listable" like Bertrand Le Roy mentions worked for me.